# Confusion regarding common references in original tree and it's copy returned by COPY-TREE

Tags: tree, lisp, common-lisp, copytree

Chapter [13. Beyond Lists: Other Uses for Cons Cells](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-lists-other-uses-for-cons-cells.html) of *Practical Common Lisp* states that objects referenced in common by the copy of the tree `((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))` returned by `COPY-TREE` and the original tree itself are the numbers 5, 6, and the symbol `NIL`.

I find it confusing because I suppose the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4 are commonly referenced too. Since numbers are immutable.

Am I wrong in my assumption?

If so, then why aren't the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4 commonly referenced?

Answer (score 1):

What it means is the every cons cell in the source is not referenced but made fresh in the result. Everything not cons is just referenced.

Yes numbers are immutable, but low numbers that fit in a pointer is not actually an object since the data is encoded in the address. In any case the "pointer address" in the `car` and `cdr` is just copied onto a new `cons` in `copy-tree` as long as it's not itself a cons cell.

`copy-list` is the same except it only does fresh cons for `cdr` and not for additional structure in `car`. It's just referenced even when it's just cons.